# ObjectFactory class generated from wsdl missing Factory Metods

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have searched for this in Internet but unable to find a answer.

I am new to SOAP services, If I am wrong at any point please correct me. I was trying to generate Java classes from wsdl using command line tool ** JAX-WS RI wsimport**. I was able to generate all Request and Response classes.
The **ObjectFactory.java** generated from wsdl was missing most of the methods.

**employee.wsdl.jaxb.bnd.xml**

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
    <jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="false">
              <xjc:serializable>
         </jaxb:globalBindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

**employee.wsdl.bnd.xml**

```
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
     xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
     wsdlLocation="../sp.wsdl">
     <jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>false</jaxws:enableWrapperStyle>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

In jaxb.bnd.xml
While trying with **<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="true">** Its able to generate all of the factory methods. But it was using **JAXBElement<>** wrapper for primititve data types like String,int,Long

While trying with **<jaxb:globalBindings generateElementProperty="fasle">** Its able to generate the class without **JAXBElement<>** wrapper, but missing most of the factory methods.

cmd: `wsimport META-INF/wsdl/employee.wsdl -keep -b META-INF/wsdl/bindings/employee.bnd.xml -b META-INF/wsdl/bindings/employee.jaxb.bnd.xml -wsdllocation META-INF/wsdl/employee.wsdl`

Sample **ObjectFactory.java**

```
package xyz;

@XmlRegistry
class ObjectFactory {
      
     private final static Qname _EmpDetailsSpecialEmpDetail_QNAME = new QName("", "scheduleEmp");
      
     @XmlElementDecl(namespce = "", name="specialEmployee", scope= EmpDetails.class)
     public SpecialEmpDetail EmpDetailsSpecialEmployee(SpecialEmpDetail value) {
           return new SpecialEmpDetail(_EmpDetailsSpecialEmpDetail_QNAME, SpecialEmpDetail.class, EmpDetail.class, value); 

}
```

EmpDetail.java

```
public class EmpDetail implements Serializable {
  @XmlElementRef(name= "specialEmployee", required=false)
  protected SpecialEmpDetail specialEmployee;
  
  public SpcialEmpDetail getSpecialEmployee() {
      return specialEmployee;
  }

  public SpcialEmpDetail setSpecialEmployee(SpcialEmpDetail value) {
      this.specialEmployee = value;
  }
}
```

SpecialEmpDetail.java

```
public class SpecialEmpDetail {
     //local var
     //getter and setter
     .....
}
```

employee.wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">
<definitions name="psp"
  targetNamespace="http://www.namespace.com/employee.wsdl"
  .....
  />
<types>
   <schmea targerNamespace = "http://www.namespace.com/employee.wsdl"
         xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:emp = "http://www.namespace.com/employee/employee.xsd1"
         <import namespace="http://www.namespace.com/employee.xsd1"/>
         <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
   </schmea>
   <schmea targerNamespace = "http://www.namespace.com/employee.xsd1"
         xmlns:SOAP-ENV = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         xmlns:emp = "http://www.namespace.com/employee/employee.xsd1"
         <import namespace="http://www.namespace.com/employee.wsdl"/>
         <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"/>
         <simpleType name="empName">
           <restrictions base="xsd:string">
           <minLength value="1"/>
           <maxLength value="30"/>
           </restrictions>
         <simpleType name="EmpID">
           <restrictions base="xsd:string">
            <minLength value="0"/>
            <maxLength value="25"/>
           </restrictions>
        </simpleType>

   <complexType name="">
     <sequence>
       <element name="specialEmployee" type="emp:SpecialEmpDetail minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </sequence>
  </complexType>
 .....
 .........
 </schema>
</types>
```

Here is the sample wsdl and java. I can able to generate `SpecialEmpDetail.java & EmpDetail.java` The `ObjectFctory.java` should create the mentioned function, but its failed to do so.... Using `JAXBElement<>` wrapper I can able to generate all functions but the problem here is its a complextType data so wrapping is fine, But `String` also wrapped this is not expected.

What may be problem?? How can  I resolve it??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Please post the ObjectFactory class and explain which methods you were expecting. If you can't post your real one, make an example .wsdl file which produces the same behaviour.

Comment: I have updated the post with sample wsdl and expected objectfactory

Comment: You have a typo: `schmea`